# Compact formulation for "the 66% of villages which are the poorest"

Tags: phrase-requests

Currently I write something along the lines of:

1. the two-thirds poorest villages
2. the poorest two-thirds of villages

But that I am not convinced that these are correct. To me the latter seems to be implying the poorest 66% of people within each village, while the former seems generally weird and unclear. Any good ideas?

Comment: Moving to common fraction format here isn't helpful. I think you're best off sticking with your original.

Comment: To me, #1 simply isn't valid English. But #2 implies that *each* village has some ascertainable level of "wealth" (presumably, independent of actual population) - from which you're excluding the wealthiest tercile to leave only the poorest two-thirds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first suggests "those villages around the 34th percentile of wealth", which I'm sure isn't what you're trying to say :o)

Your second example is fine. ***The poorest two thirds*** (I wouldn’t hyphenate it) means exactly what you want, and unless you were to say ***of each village*** hopefully should not be confused with that meaning.

I'd suggest using ***poorer*** rather than ***poorest*** though, because ***-est*** suggests a very small minority of something, and you’re talking about a majority.